# How can I add, remove and remove all in session array values in php?

Tags: php

In this code, I can't fetch id value. How can I give a number instead of `if(strlen)` ? And how can I give remove one by one item ?

```
<?Php
    @$product=$_POST['product'];

    if (strlen($product)>3) {
        array_push($_SESSION['cart'],$product); // Items added to cart
    }
?>

<?Php
    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {

        echo " <br><a href=cart-remove-all.php>Remove all</a><br>";
        while (list ($key, $val) = each ($_SESSION['cart'])) { 
            echo "$key -> $val <br>"; 
        } else {
            echo " Session Cart is not created. Visit <a href=cart.php>cart.php</a> page 
to create the array and add products to it. ";
        }
?>

<form method="post">  
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $row['jobtitle'];?>">
    <input type="submit" style="float:right;font-size:15px;font-weight:600;" value="+ Add to Short List">
</form>
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear (at least to me). You should be more specific about what doesn't work or what you want to achieve.

Comment: if(strlen($product)>3) in this part we can give strings only, how can I fetch numbers instead strlen. And how can I delete items in one by one?

Answer (score 0):

to remove all, just do :

```
unset($_SESSION['cart']);
```

and, rather than using a while loop, you can use foreach loop.you can remove the item by using its array index in $_SESSION['cart'];

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response. I ask one by one item delete not remove all.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question clearly, you can use

```
if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][0]))
unset($_SESSION['cart'][0]);
```

Likewise, you can change 0,1,2...n to unset the nth record. BTW, once you unset one record the number of records in the array will become n-1 from n. if you keep doing the above code repeatedly until the count of the records become 0 also will work

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$value){
    if($ke==="yourkey"){
        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]); 
    }

}
```

**yourkey** is the key, you want to remove.